# Is it possible to do 'recursive parametric polymorphism' in C#

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

So I am working with .NET Core, and I am working out some data contracts that need to be expandable, to this end, I intend to use parametric polymorphism aka generics.

Now, My sample interfaces and classes here look like so:

```
public interface IEmailAttachment<TEmail, TAttachment> where TEmail : IEmail<TAttachment> where TAttachment : IEmailAttachment<IEmail<TAttachment>, TAttachment>
{
    ...
    TEmail Email { get; set; }
    ...
}

public interface IEmail<TAttachment> where TAttachment : IEmailAttachment<IEmail<TAttachment>, TAttachment>
{
    ...
    IEnumerable<TAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class DefaultEmail : IEmail<DefaultEmailAttachment>
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<DefaultEmailAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class DefaultEmailAttachment : IEmailAttachment<DefaultEmail, DefaultEmailAttachment>
{
    ...
    public DefaultEmail Email { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

However, this does not work. I get this error:

For the DefaultEmail class:

> The type 'DefaultEmailAttachment' cannot be used as type parameter
> 'TAttachment' in the generic type or method 'IEmail'.
> There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'DefaultEmailAttachment' to
> 'IEmailAttachment<IEmail,
> DefaultEmailAttachment>'.

For the DefaultEmailAttachment:

> The type 'DefaultEmailAttachment' cannot be used as type parameter
> 'TAttachment' in the generic type or method 'IEmailAttachment<TEmail,
> TAttachment>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'DefaultEmailAttachment' to
> 'IEmailAttachment<IEmail,
> DefaultEmailAttachment>'.

I realise it is probably because I am assuming a bit much, and likely cycling with the type parameters, but if I am missing something obvious that would make this work, please inform me, or suggest another idea of how this could work.

Answer (score 1):

While this sort of contracts seem to be a good idea in the beginning, you inevitably run into a cascade of (often insovable) problems. Also, this construct is very inflexible. How are you going to add attachments of different types to an email or different types of mails to an email list?

And how are you going to create emails for different types of attachments dynamically?

While being flexible at design-time, generics are not dynamic. This means that the concrete types must be known at compile time.

The fundamental questions are:

- Do you really need different types of email for different types of attachments?
- Why do the attachments need to know the exact type of the email?
- Wouldn't classic polymorphism be sufficient and more flexible?

There is also a way in between. Often a way out to this sort of problem is to have a non-generic base interface (or class) and derived generic types:

```
public interface IAttachment
{
    IEmail Email { get; set; } // Only reference the non-generic base interface.
}

public interface IEmail
{
    // Only members not requiring a generic type parameter. 
}

public interface IEmail<TAttachment> where TAttachment : IAttachment
{
    ICollection<TAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can have a list of different types of email

```
var mails = new List<IEmail>();
mails.Add(new EMail<SpecificAttatchment>());
mails.Add(new EMail<DefaultAttatchment>()); // or
mails.Add(new DefaultEmail());
```

This is slightly more flexible, but you still have the problem of accessing the attachments of the different `IEmail<T>` types at runtime. I don't know what type of problem you are trying to solve with this recursive parametric polymorphism, but I would go with non-generic `IAttachment` and `IEmail` interfaces alone. If generic type parameters are still required, try to avoid recursions.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a bunch for taking the time to write this out! The idea is simply to make something, that I can shove into something like EF. I want to create something that a service I create can use, because it implements my interfaces, but later I can reimplement the classes in case I need other fields the service isn't concerned with. I guess I don't NEED it to work the way I'm trying to here, just had the idea and had to try it, failing to get it to work I desired the eyes of someone more experienced with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Olivier raises some good points. I agree with all his sentiments, and would not recomment this approach particularly because of how difficult it is to understand the constraints. However, yes, it is possible to implement. It becomes a lot easier to understand if both classes have the same parameters and the same constraints:

```
public interface IEmailAttachment<TEmail, TAttachment> where TEmail : IEmail<TEmail, TAttachment> where TAttachment : IEmailAttachment<TEmail, TAttachment>
{
    TEmail Email { get; set; }
}

public interface IEmail<TEmail, TAttachment> where TEmail : IEmail<TEmail, TAttachment> where TAttachment : IEmailAttachment<TEmail, TAttachment>
{
    IEnumerable<TAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultEmail : IEmail<DefaultEmail, DefaultEmailAttachment>
{
    public IEnumerable<DefaultEmailAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultEmailAttachment : IEmailAttachment<DefaultEmail, DefaultEmailAttachment>
{
    public DefaultEmail Email { get; set; }
}
```

The error you are currently seeing is because `Foo<Derived>` is not assignable to `Foo<Base>` by default. `IEmailAttachment<DefaultEmail, DefaultEmailAttachment>` is not the same as `IEmailAttachment<IEmail<DefaultEmailAttachment>, DefaultEmailAttachment>`. This problem could possibly be solved with *covariance*, but it would restrict you to getters only instead of get/set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your suggestion here is much appreciated. I'm not sure I follow why this is so terrible. I think the idea is fine for what I need it to be: an entity in EF (or something similar)

Comment: I think instead of expecting to be able to directly map these with entity framework (Which I assume is why you need the entities to be referencing concrete types instead of interfaces), you'd be better off creating an abstraction over the storage layer, i.e. a generic IRepository<TEmail> interface. An example of this is the Asp.Net Identity classes (UserManager and RoleManager)

Comment: Actually the idea is to have an interface with the necessary IQueryable's. So when this is implements I know the necessary data (that residing in the email related interfaces) is available. I'll try and see how I could go about it differently.

Comment: You could pose this as a question on Code Review or Software Design to get people's opinions/suggestions and the reasoning behind them